# ruby puts command

Tags: ruby, irb

I have just started to learn "Ruby" (like 2 mins before) , searched on google for [tutorial](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/)

I was trying the `puts` command, where I accidently wrote

```
irb(main):005:0> puts "nil:
irb(main):006:0" puts :
irb(main):007:0" puts "nil:
irb(main):008:0* puts "nil:
irb(main):009:0" puts "nil:
irb(main):010:0*
```

I noticed the change in prompt `>` to `"` and then `*` , I really dont know what it is, could somebody explain what just happened ?

Thank you :)

By the way, if its important, I have downloaded this [ruby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Comment: i wonder why wont you close your string? `puts "nil:"`

Comment: changing from `>` to `"` means it is waiting for more input

Comment: and it works as expected now?

Comment: @slivu : ohkkie.. thanks.. and what does `"` to `*`  means?

Comment: @slivu : yea it did work the first time, I read that `puts` returns `nil` all the time, so i was just fooling around, trying to do `puts nil` and `puts "nil"` and made a typo. So got curious and posted it up..Thanks a lot for the quick response :)

Comment: a beginning of some statement. in line 3 you closed you string and used `nil`

Comment: @slivu : ok,got it. Could you post that as an answer? So i could accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i wonder why wont you close your string?

should be:

```
puts "nil:"
```

changing from `>` to `"` means it is waiting for more input

changing from `"` to `*` means a beginning of a statement - in line 3 you closed you string and used `nil`

Comment: Thanks for your help, and as clarified in comments to OP, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

IRB is waiting for you to finish the string, like @peterpan said, IRB is able to handle multiple lines.

The `*` you are seeing is because when you write the last `puts "nil:` you are effectively closing the first string, and IRB is seeing now the beginning of a hash `nil:`, so its expecting a value of the key `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

IRB is expecting the end of a string. You haven't closed your string on the first, so the prompt shows this with the ". Strings can span multiple lines in the irb prompt.

Comment: That doesn't explain the difference between `"` and `*`.

Comment: @sawa I can't replicate the * but I believe it means that irb is expecting the close of a hash key pair.

Comment: Not that surprising, either. Combining the input, it's `puts "nil\nputs :\nputs "` and `nil:...` so that'd be your key-pair.

Answer (score 0):

Hold control and tap C.  That will clear you out.  It's waiting for more input.  You need to use the command as

```
puts "nil:"
puts "string here"
puts variable_here
```